# Cython allocate memory for array without using python

Tags: python, cython

I'm trying to Cythonize a simple function and I want to be able to compile it with the `nogil` statement. What I have (in a jupyter notebook) is:

```py
%%cython -a
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from libc.math cimport exp, pi

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef double[:, ::1] _gauss(Py_ssize_t yw, Py_ssize_t xw, double y0, double x0, double sy, double sx):
    """Simple normalized 2D gaussian function for rendering"""
    # for this model, x and y are seperable, so we can generate
    # two gaussians and take the outer product
    cdef double amp = 1 / (2 * pi * sy * sx)

    cdef double[:, ::1] result = np.empty((yw, xw), dtype=np.float64)

    cdef Py_ssize_t x, y

    for y in range(yw):
        for x in range(xw):
            result[y, x] = exp(-((y - y0) / sy) ** 2 / 2 - ((x - x0) / sx) ** 2 / 2) * amp

    return result

def gauss(yw, xw, y0, x0, sy, sx):
    return _gauss(yw, xw, y0, x0, sy, sx)
```

Which compiles fine. If I change the first `cdef` line to read:

```
...
cdef double[:, ::1] _gauss(Py_ssize_t yw, Py_ssize_t xw, double y0, double x0, double sy, double sx) nogil:
...
```

Then the compilation fails because the first and third `cdef` lines interact with the python interpreter and I'm not sure why (especially for the first one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The creation of a typed memoryview object results in interaction with the GIL because it *is* a python object. For that reason, you would not be able to return a new typed memoryview object from a `cdef nogil function.` However, there are several ways to get around this limitation with the GIL.

One option would be to just release the GIL within the function. This can be done using a `with nogil:` block that can be placed around the iterating code. This function would look as follows:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cdef double[:, ::1] _gauss(Py_ssize_t yw, Py_ssize_t xw, double y0, double x0, double sy, double sx):
    #Do gil-interacting, python stuff here
    cdef double amp = 1 / (2 * pi * sy * sx)
    cdef double[:, ::1] result = np.empty((yw, xw), dtype=np.float64)
    cdef Py_ssize_t x, y

    with nogil:
        #And now basically write C code
        for y in range(yw):
            for x in range(xw):
                result[y, x] = exp(-((y - y0) / sy) ** 2 / 2 - ((x - x0) / sx) ** 2 / 2) * amp
    return result
```

Another option would be to have the user pass in a numpy array of type `double[:, ::1]`. That way, memory is not allocated within the function itself. Using that approach, `_gauss` could be declared `cdef nogil`.

If you are really concerned about the overhead of allocating memory for the numpy array, you could try to use C-style functions like `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, and `free` to manage your memory. This pointer could then be cast to an appropriate typed memoryview; however, doing so will invoke the gil upon creation of said memoryview.